# C# thread invoke freezing window

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, invoke

This is code freezing current window. How to made non freezing this form.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Thread t;

    int s = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        label2.Text = "Push the Button";
        button1.Text = "Push me!";
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);

        this.Controls.Add(label2);
        this.Controls.Add(button1);
    }

    void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunMe));
        t.Start();
    }

    private void RunMe()
    {
            if (!InvokeRequired)
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    label2.Text = s.ToString();
                    s++;
                    Task.Delay(10000).Wait(10000);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Invoke(new ThreadStart(RunMe));
            }
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: `Invoke` runs some code on the UI thread, so you're actually running your *entire endless loop* on the UI thread, causing it to be permanently blocked.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, you are using the UI thread to execute an endless loop, you should use the `Timer` control, it was built for exactly what you're doing.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/43daf8b2-67ad-4938-98f7-cae3eaa5e63f/how-to-use-timer-control-in-c?forum=winforms

Answer (score 1):

Your code can benefit from using `async-await` if you are using .net 4.5. Using `await` you won't have to start a seperate thread for your `RunMe` method, it will free up your UI thread to do other work but the SynchronizationContext is captured so that you don't have to use `Invoke` to update the UI. For how that works, see [this blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

I think you should be able to rewrite your code like this:

```
async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    // kicks off the RunMe method and returns
    await RunMe();
}

private Task RunMe()
{
    while(true)
    {
        label2.Text = s.ToString();
        s++;
        await Task.Delay(10000);
    }    
}
```

Despite the infinite `while` loop the method only wakes up to update the label and runs for a very short time in the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the invoke only for updating the label like this:

```
while(true)
{
    if (!InvokeRequired)
    {
        label2.Text = s.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        Invoke(new Action(()=>{label2.Text = s.ToString();}));
    }
    s++;
    Task.Delay(10000).Wait(10000);
}
```

Comment: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type